# Cannot open raw files from cloudinary in django admin

Tags: django, cloudinary

I do config the raw file's storage to couldinary and I can't open it in django admin(it shown 404 error). Did I miss something?

I have set the storage location in setting.py as below:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.MediaCloudinaryStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE1 = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.RawMediaCloudinaryStorage'

CLOUDINARY_STORAGE = {
 'CLOUD_NAME': 'XXXXX',
 'API_KEY': 'XXXXXX',
 'API_SECRET': 'XXXX-XXXXX',
}

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE


CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
  'default': {
      'toolbar': None,
  },
 }
```

Added to urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('team_profile.urls')),
path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),

 ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE)
```

Set the raw file's upload path in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
from cloudinary_storage.storage import RawMediaCloudinaryStorage

class apply_position(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=8)
mail = models.EmailField(blank=False)
file = models.FileField(upload_to='add/file_save/', null=False, storage=RawMediaCloudinaryStorage())
time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

The forms.py is fine and I've put it to the views.py

```
def recruit(request):
form = addForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
else:
    form = addForm()
```

The Error I got when I try to open the files in admin site:

```
https://res.cloudinary.com/xxxxx/raw/upload/v1/media/add/file_save/xxxx.pdf 
  HTTP ERROR 404
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDf's in cloudinary considers as image files. can you please try to upload them as such and let us know if that helps?
Also, Based on a recent update to our security policies, we've restricted delivery on newly created Free accounts for PDFs and Archive files. Such files can still be uploaded, but the restriction is specifically on delivery.

If you have a free account, please contact support@cloudinary.com with your cloud name and more details about your use-case and we can remove this restriction on your account.

Best,
Shirly